# Paste `shell-command-to-string` result after cursor position

Tags: config

I use `shell-command-to-string` to automate some common tasks. However, these strings must be pasted after the cursor. **How can I configure `shell-command-to-string` to paste after the current cursor position, not before?**

I do use `evil` if that detail is important. I'm looking for the equivalent of `p`, not `P`. I am usually, but not always, pasting at the end of the current line.

For example, one of my usages is to paste an Org mode formatted link of the page currently open in Firefox:

```
(defun ff-link-org ()
    (interactive)
    (insert (shell-command-to-string "lz4jsoncat $FIREFOX_DIR/sessionstore-backups/recovery.jsonlz4 | jq -r '.windows[0].t    abs | sort_by(.lastAccessed)[-1] | .entries[.index-1] | \"[[\" + (.url) + \"][\" + (.title) + \"]]\"' | tr -d '\n'"))
)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c f") 'ff-link-org)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don’t configure `shell-command-to-string`, what you do is save the current position and then jump back to it. You could do it like this:

```
(defun ff-link-org ()
    (interactive)
    (let ((pos (point)))
        (insert (shell-command-to-string "lz4jsoncat $FIREFOX_DIR/sessionstore-backups/recovery.jsonlz4 | jq -r '.windows[0].t    abs | sort_by(.lastAccessed)[-1] | .entries[.index-1] | \"[[\" + (.url) + \"][\" + (.title) + \"]]\"' | tr -d '\n'"))
        (goto-char pos)))
```

However, that kind of thing happens so frequently that people got tired of typing it all out and made a macro called `save-excursion` which does all of the work for you:

```
(defun ff-link-org ()
    (interactive)
    (save-excursion
        (insert (shell-command-to-string "lz4jsoncat $FIREFOX_DIR/sessionstore-backups/recovery.jsonlz4 | jq -r '.windows[0].t    abs | sort_by(.lastAccessed)[-1] | .entries[.index-1] | \"[[\" + (.url) + \"][\" + (.title) + \"]]\"' | tr -d '\n'"))))
```

Comment: Thank you. I suppose that Evil is the culprit, but the behaviour when wrapped with `save-excursion` is the same as without. However, with both methods, from Normal mode (i.e. not Insert mode) I can run the shortcut and it pastes at the current location.

Comment: Honestly, that sounds like a bug in evil. Perhaps you should try reporting it to the evil developers.

Comment: I'll consult with the evil devs, thank you.